# How do simplicies related to complexes?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am just starting to learn about Cell complexes, CW complexes, and simplices. I have an okay understanding of how each are defined, but it is extremely abstract, and therefore I am really struggling to see how they overlap or tie into each other. I have a feeling that it could be explained in a simple way, but my book doesn't do it and I can't find a nice explanation online. Can someone help me draw some conclusions about how Complexes and simpices relate (or do not relate) to one another? I realize that this is a painfully generalized question, but it's because my knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

I think my book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) should help since it gives in Chapter $4$ a careful introduction to adjunction spaces and finite cell complexes, and in Section $5.5$
deals with simplicial complexes, see $5.5.3$.